# How to get Elastic Search aggregation to mirror the query filtering logic?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

On our site we allow users to filter Elastic Search results with a set of filters divided into categories:

```
A
  A1
  A2
  ...
B
  B1
  B2
  B3
  ...
```

These are just matching on literal tags that can appear in a field of the document, like:

```
{ tags: ["A1", "B1", "B2"] }
```

Our existing query joins all the filter terms under AND, so if the user selects `A1`, `B1`, and `B2`, we filter by `(A1 AND B1 AND B2)`.

We want to change this to "OR within each filter category", and "AND across categories", so that you'd get: `(A1) AND (B1 OR B2)`.

Now, the wrinkle: we also use a "terms" aggregation on the "tags" field to predict how many items would come back from applying the next filter. On our UI this looks like:

```
A
  A1   12   # If the user adds the A1 filter, there'll be 12 results.
  A2   3    # etc.
  ...
B
  B1   5
  B2   0
  B3   2
  ...
```

Here, changing the filter logic to AND/OR breaks the counts that come back from the "terms" aggregation, because the terms aggregation is still predicting `A1 AND B1 AND B2`. Adding `B3` would get us `A1 AND B1 AND B2 AND B3` and thus narrow the counts from the aggregations, whereas it would actually widen the scope of the results (we'd want `(A1) AND (B1 OR B2 OR B3)`).

Is there a way to express this in aggregations so that the filtering logic and the aggregation counts match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Filter aggregation` that constructs buckets based on anything you could also use as filters in a regular query. This can work if you are able to construct the filters beforehand and there are not too many possible values because you would need to define one filter bucket for each "next" combination. Please be aware that this could have performance implications when compared with a simple `Terms aggregation`.

For details please see the docs at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

Comment: Interesting - so I'd need to send something like (current filter + A1), (current filter + A2), etc., one for each possible next filter? We have a few hundred filters operating over five or six thousand documents -- would this approach still be the way to go?

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure if it's such a good solution when you have many different tags (terms) for which you need to construct the "next" filters. Elasticsearch does a great job when it comes to caching and reusing (parts of) filters, so I think you could try it. Five or six thousand are also not that many documents. It's more about constructing the aggregation and afterwards extracting the results manually. Probably there is a way to not display all results at once?

Comment: Thanks, got this approach working today (ES 1.7). I'm bumping into a limit somewhere (could be in our stack someplace) that's limiting my filters aggregation to ~200 buckets, though.